# NEO4J: caption value in node not display?

Tags: neo4j

try create 2 nodes and relation them, but caption not appear in second node "water"

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can really only pick one field per label to use as the identifier for the Neo4j Browser, as typically you'd expect there to be only one main human-readable identifier for a given *thing* in a data model. You've here got two concepts ('Medicine', in your model) that have very different ways of identifying them which isn't *wrong* but is probably unhelpful.

For example, a Person label might have a `name` field, a Car label might have a `model` field and so on - you wouldn't typically have a mix of the two, but the two labels might co-exist in the same graph and you could set the browser up to use `name` on `Person` nodes and `model` on `Car` nodes.

Your data model's a bit odd to my eyes which might be the cause of the confusion - why are m1 and m2 both `Medicine`s, when m1 seems to really be a symptom of a disease? The node labels in the model ideally would be the nouns or concepts of your domain, and the relationships the verbs that relate them.

For example, I personally would model what you've put as an example as follows:

```
CREATE (s: Symptom { name: 'Fever' })
CREATE (m: Medicine { name: 'Water', chemicalName: 'Dihydrogen oxide' })
CREATE (m)-[:TREATS]->(s)
RETURN m, s
```

You could elect to use `chemicalName` as the label for your `Medicine` nodes, or just the plain `name` field as you see fit - but they would all then render consistently in the graph visualisation.

[image]